# Get startDate and endDate of week when pressing forward button or previous button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. Which is the best way to get startDate and endDate of a week by pressing previous button to move one week backwards and next button to move one week forward?
[image]

The text showing the dates defaults to the current week. I want when a user presses next to be able to update the text with the next week's start and end dates and vice versa when the user presses previous

Comment: What's your definition of *start of week* and *end of week*? Any specific days, like Friday, Saturday, Sunday or Monday? Do you know `java.time`?

Comment: Start and end week should be Monday - Sunday @deeHaar

Comment: Take the `fun` from my answer, use it to get *next Sunday* from *today* and you have the date to display next to the *Next* button. You can use it to subtract days in order to get *last Monday*, which is what to display after the *Previous* button. Then use the same method to adjust the dates when *Next* is clicked and write a `fun` that determines the previous Monday and use that when *Previous* gets clicked.

Comment: By the way, the image in your question clearly shows a 5-day week, no weekend days, most likely. Are you sure you don't want that?

Comment: Thank you so much @deHaar About the image that should be 7days Monday-Sunday. Was a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not mention which day of week is actually determining a start of an end of a week in your situation/culture/country.
That's why I can only come up with a `fun` that accepts a `java.time.DayOfWeek` as the only argument and calculates the next `java.time.LocalDate` with that `DayOfWeek` in the future. Fortunately, Kotlin provides the concept of *extension functions*, which means you can simply attach a new `fun` to `LocalDate` like this:

```kotlin
fun LocalDate.getNext(weekday: DayOfWeek): LocalDate {
    // add one day to have tomorrow
    var next = this.plusDays(1)
    // then start checking the days of week until the given one is reached
    while (next.dayOfWeek != weekday) next = next.plusDays(1)
    // when reached, return the result
    return next
}
```

You can use it in a main like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val today = LocalDate.now()
    println("Today ($today) is ${today.dayOfWeek.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH)}")
    val nextFriday = today.getNext(DayOfWeek.FRIDAY)
    println("Next Friday is $nextFriday")
    val nextMonday = today.getNext(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
    println("Next Monday is $nextMonday")
}
```

This outputs

```kotlin
Today (2021-11-25) is Thursday
Next Friday is 2021-11-26
Next Monday is 2021-11-29
```

Ok, that's only half of your requirements, but I think you are able to write (nearly) the same `fun` that gets you the date of the *previous* day of week instead of the upcoming one. Let's call it `getPrevious(weekday: DayOfWeek)`, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your response @deHaar gives me an idea on how to go about this. Please see attached screenshot on my question for better explanation of my requirement. The text showing the dates defaults to the current week. I want when a user presses next to be able to update the text with the next week's start and end dates and vice versa when the user presses previous

Answer (score 1):

Here is example how to get startWeekDate.

```
private fun getStartWeekDate(){
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val currentDayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    val daysAfterSunday = currentDayOfWeek - Calendar.SUNDAY
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysAfterSunday)
    val theDateForSunday = cal.time
}
```

for the endDate()

```
private fun getEndWeekDate(){
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    val currentDayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
    val daysBeforeSaturday = currentDayOfWeek - Calendar.SATURDAY
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -daysBeforeSaturday)
    val theDateForSaturday = cal.time
}
```